# Using SqlBulkCopy with MongoDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

From a previous question, I'm trying to do a `SqlBulkCopy` from a MongoDB database, and I'm getting an error and can't find what column type I should have:

> The given value of type `ObjectId` from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column.

[image]

Where my `DataTable` Column `DataType` is `MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId`.

**What should be the type** in Microsoft Sql Server to host this value?

My current code:

```
string connectionString = GetDestinationConnectionString();
var mongoCollection = GetSourceConnectionString();

var queryFind = Query.And(Query.NotExists("sync"), Query.NotIn("challenge_guid", new List<MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue>() { "87558b59-73ee-4f10-add4-b9031551e395" }));
var sourceData = mongoCollection.Find(queryFind).ToList();

DataTable dt = CollectionHelper.ConvertTo<MongoAnswerDoc>(sourceData);

using (SqlConnection destinationConnection =
            new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    destinationConnection.Open();

    // Set up the bulk copy object. 
    // Note that the column positions in the source
    // data reader match the column positions in 
    // the destination table so there is no need to
    // map columns.
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "JK_RawChallengeAnswers";

        try
        {
            // Write from the source to the destination.
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtMsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Dispose of the DataTable.
            dt.Dispose();
            // close connection
            destinationConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Mongo spec](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/):

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
>
> - a 4-byte timestamp,
> - a 3-byte machine identifier,
> - a 2-byte process id, and
> - a 3-byte counter.

So you would need a [`BINARY(12)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) type column to map it in SQL.

Anyway, your code will run out of memory on any transfer of significance, using an intermediate DataTable in-memory copy is not the way to go. [`EnableStreaming`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.enablestreaming.aspx) and use an [`IDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx) to iterate over the source just-in-time.

Comment: I would I go by converting a `Mongo.Cursor` (witch is the output from the query) to an `IDataReader` without creating a new object and implementing it?

Comment: Is not hard, you only need a very basic IDataReader implementation. Have a look at http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/aviwortzel/archive/2008/05/06/implementing-sqlbulkcopy-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: More examples: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/122498/using-sqlbulkcopy-for-high-performance-inserts/ , http://www.csvreader.com/posts/generic_list_datareader.php